# How to turn on optimizations ( O3 ) when invoking cmake?

Tags: cmake, compiler-optimization, mlpack

I am trying to build mlpack from source,

So far I have compiled the library with the below command,

`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\msys64\mingw64\include" -DBUILD_BINDINGS=OFF -DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Users\Shoyeb\Downloads\armadillo-11.0.1.tar\armadillo-11.0.1\include"`

when I invoked mingw32-make,

I got the below error,

[image]

Error says file too big.

How to invoke cmake with optimization flags like O3,

Below are the contents of CMakeLists.txt,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3.2)
project(mlpack C CXX)

include(CMake/cotire.cmake)
include(CMake/CheckHash.cmake)

# First, define all the compilation options.
# We default to debugging mode for developers.
option(DEBUG "Compile with debugging information." OFF)
option(PROFILE "Compile with profiling information." OFF)
option(ARMA_EXTRA_DEBUG "Compile with extra Armadillo debugging symbols." OFF)
option(MATLAB_BINDINGS "Compile MATLAB bindings if MATLAB is found." OFF)
option(TEST_VERBOSE "Run test cases with verbose output." OFF)
option(BUILD_TESTS "Build tests." ON)
option(BUILD_CLI_EXECUTABLES "Build command-line executables." ON)
option(DISABLE_DOWNLOADS "Disable downloads of dependencies during build." OFF)
option(DOWNLOAD_ENSMALLEN "If ensmallen is not found, download it." ON)
option(DOWNLOAD_STB_IMAGE "Download stb_image for image loading." ON)
option(BUILD_GO_SHLIB "Build Go shared library." OFF)

# Set minimum library version required by mlpack.
set(ARMADILLO_VERSION "8.400.0")
set(ENSMALLEN_VERSION "2.10.0")
set(BOOST_VERSION "1.58")

if (WIN32)
  option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
      "Compile shared libraries (if OFF, static libraries are compiled)." OFF)

  set(DLL_COPY_DIRS "" CACHE STRING "List of directories (separated by ';') containing DLLs to copy for runtime.")
  set(DLL_COPY_LIBS "" CACHE STRING "List of DLLs (separated by ';') that should be copied for runtime.")
else ()
  option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
      "Compile shared libraries (if OFF, static libraries are compiled)." ON)
endif()

# Detect whether the user passed BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS in order to determine if
# we should fail if Python isn't found.
if (BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS)
  set(FORCE_BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS ON)
else()
  set(FORCE_BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS OFF)
endif()
option(BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS "Build Python bindings." OFF)

# Detect whether the user passed BUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS in order to determine if
# we should fail if Julia isn't found.
if (BUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS)
  set(FORCE_BUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS ON)
else()
  set(FORCE_BUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS OFF)
endif()
option(BUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS "Build Julia bindings." ON)

# Detect whether the user passed BUILD_GO_BINDINGS in order to determine if
# we should fail if Go isn't found.
if (BUILD_GO_BINDINGS)
  set(FORCE_BUILD_GO_BINDINGS ON)
else()
  set(FORCE_BUILD_GO_BINDINGS OFF)
endif()
option(BUILD_GO_BINDINGS "Build Go bindings." ON)

# If building Go bindings then build go shared libraries.
if (BUILD_GO_BINDINGS)
  set(BUILD_GO_SHLIB ON)
endif()

# Detect whether the user passed BUILD_R_BINDINGS in order to determine if
# we should fail if R isn't found.
if (BUILD_R_BINDINGS)
  set(FORCE_BUILD_R_BINDINGS ON)
else()
  set(FORCE_BUILD_R_BINDINGS OFF)
endif()
option(BUILD_R_BINDINGS "Build R bindings." ON)
# Build Markdown bindings for documentation.  This is used as part of website
# generation.
option(BUILD_MARKDOWN_BINDINGS "Build Markdown bindings for website documentation." OFF)

option(BUILD_WITH_COVERAGE
    "Build with support for code coverage tools (gcc only)." OFF)
option(MATHJAX
    "Use MathJax for HTML Doxygen output (disabled by default)." OFF)
option(FORCE_CXX11
    "Don't check that the compiler supports C++11, just assume it.  Make sure to specify any necessary flag to enable C++11 as part of CXXFLAGS." OFF)
option(USE_OPENMP "If available, use OpenMP for parallelization." ON)
enable_testing()

# Set required standard to C++11.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Include modules in the CMake directory.
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake")

# Disable any downloads if needed.
if (DISABLE_DOWNLOADS)
  set(DOWNLOAD_ENSMALLEN OFF)
  set(DOWNLOAD_STB_IMAGE OFF)
endif ()

# If we are on a Unix-like system, use the GNU install directories module.
# Otherwise set the values manually.
if (UNIX)
  include(GNUInstallDirs)
else ()
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/man)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/doc/mlpack)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
endif ()

# This is as of yet unused.
#option(PGO "Use profile-guided optimization if not a debug build" ON)

# Set the CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS depending on the options the user specified.
# Only GCC-like compilers support -Wextra, and other compilers give tons of
# output for -Wall, so only -Wall and -Wextra on GCC.
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  # Ensure that we can't compile with clang 3.4, since this causes strange
  # issues.
  if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.5)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "mlpack does not build correctly with clang < 3.5.  "
        "Please upgrade your compiler and reconfigure mlpack.")
  endif ()

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -ftemplate-depth=1000")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")

  # To remove unused functions warnings.
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-function")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-function")
endif()

# These support libraries are used if we need to link against something
# specific.  This list is a subset of MLPACK_LIBRARIES.
set(COMPILER_SUPPORT_LIBRARIES "")

# If we are using MSVC, we need /bigobj.
if (MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /bigobj")
endif ()

# If we are using MINGW, we need sections and big-obj, otherwise we create too
# many sections.
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC AND WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wa,-mbig-obj")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wa,-mbig-obj")
endif()

# If using clang, we have to link against libc++ depending on the
# OS (at least on some systems). Further, gcc sometimes optimizes calls to
# math.h functions, making -lm unnecessary with gcc, but it may still be
# necessary with clang.
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  if (APPLE)
    # Detect OS X version. Use '/usr/bin/sw_vers -productVersion' to
    # extract V from '10.V.x'.
    exec_program(/usr/bin/sw_vers ARGS
        -productVersion OUTPUT_VARIABLE MACOSX_VERSION_RAW)
    string(REGEX REPLACE
        "10\\.([0-9]+).*" "\\1"
        MACOSX_VERSION
        "${MACOSX_VERSION_RAW}")

     # OSX Lion (10.7) and OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) doesn't automatically
     # select the right stdlib.
    if(${MACOSX_VERSION} LESS 9)
      set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
      set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
          "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
      set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
          "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
      set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
     endif()
  endif()

  # Link everything with -lm.
  set(COMPILER_SUPPORT_LIBRARIES ${COMPILER_SUPPORT_LIBRARIES} "m")
  set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES} "m")
  # Use -pthread, but not on OS X.
  if (NOT APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
  endif ()
endif()

# If we're using gcc, then we need to link against pthreads to use std::thread,
# which we do in the tests.
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
  find_package(Threads)
  set(COMPILER_SUPPORT_LIBRARIES ${COMPILER_SUPPORT_LIBRARIES}
      ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
endif()

# Setup build for test coverage
if(BUILD_WITH_COVERAGE)
  # Currently coverage only works with GNU g++.
  if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    # Find gcov and lcov
    find_program(GCOV gcov)
    find_program(LCOV lcov)

    if(NOT GCOV)
      message(FATAL_ERROR
          "gcov not found! gcov is required when BUILD_WITH_COVERAGE=ON.")
    endif()

    set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES} "supc++")
    set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES} "quadmath")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage -fno-inline -fno-inline-small-functions -fno-default-inline -fprofile-arcs -fkeep-inline-functions")
    message(STATUS "Adding debug compile options for code coverage.")
    # Remove optimizations for better line coverage
    set(DEBUG ON)

    if(LCOV)
      configure_file(CMake/mlpack_coverage.in mlpack_coverage @ONLY)
      add_custom_target(mlpack_coverage DEPENDS mlpack_test COMMAND ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mlpack_coverage)
    else()
      message(WARNING "'lcov' not found; local coverage report is disabled. "
          "Install 'lcov' and rerun cmake to generate local coverage report.")
    endif()
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "BUILD_WITH_COVERAGE can only work with GNU environment.")
  endif()
endif()

# Debugging CFLAGS.  Turn optimizations off; turn debugging symbols on.
if(DEBUG)
  if (NOT MSVC)
    add_definitions(-DDEBUG)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99 -g -O0")
  endif()

  # mlpack uses it's own mlpack::backtrace class based on Binary File Descriptor
  # <bfd.h> and linux Dynamic Loader <libdl.h> and more portable version in future
  if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
    find_package(Bfd)
    find_package(LibDL)
    if(LIBBFD_FOUND AND LIBDL_FOUND)
      set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -rdynamic")
      set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBBFD_INCLUDE_DIRS}
          ${LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
      set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES} ${LIBBFD_LIBRARIES}
          ${LIBDL_LIBRARIES})
      add_definitions(-DHAS_BFD_DL)
    else()
      message(WARNING "No libBFD and/or libDL has been found!")
    endif()
  endif()
else()
  add_definitions(-DARMA_NO_DEBUG)
  add_definitions(-DNDEBUG)
  if (NOT MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99 -O3")
  else ()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /O3")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /O3")
  endif ()
endif()

# Profiling CFLAGS.  Turn profiling information on.
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC AND PROFILE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -pg")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
endif()

# If the user asked for running test cases with verbose output, turn that on.
if(TEST_VERBOSE)
  add_definitions(-DTEST_VERBOSE)
endif()

# If the user asked for extra Armadillo debugging output, turn that on.
if(ARMA_EXTRA_DEBUG)
  add_definitions(-DARMA_EXTRA_DEBUG)
endif()

# Now, find the libraries we need to compile against.  Several variables can be
# set to manually specify the directory in which each of these libraries
# resides.
#   ARMADILLO_LIBRARY - location of libarmadillo.so / armadillo.lib
#   ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR - directory containing <armadillo>
#   ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS - directories necessary for Armadillo includes
#   BOOST_ROOT - root of Boost installation
#   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR - include directory for Boost
#   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR - library directory for Boost
#   ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR - include directory for ensmallen
#   STB_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR - include directory for STB image library
#   MATHJAX_ROOT - root of MathJax installation
find_package(Armadillo "${ARMADILLO_VERSION}" REQUIRED)

# Include directories for the previous dependencies.
set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES} ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})

# Find stb_image.h and stb_image_write.h.
find_package(StbImage)
# Download stb_image for image loading.
if (NOT STB_IMAGE_FOUND)
  if (DOWNLOAD_STB_IMAGE)
    set(STB_DIR "stb")
    install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}")
    file(DOWNLOAD http://mlpack.org/files/stb-2.22/stb_image.h
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/stb_image.h"
        STATUS STB_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST LOG STB_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOG
        SHOW_PROGRESS)
    list(GET STB_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST 0 STB_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)
    file(DOWNLOAD http://mlpack.org/files/stb-1.13/stb_image_write.h
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/stb_image_write.h"
        STATUS STB_IMAGE_WRITE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST
        LOG STB_IMAGE_WRITE_DOWNLOAD_LOG
        SHOW_PROGRESS)
    list(GET STB_IMAGE_WRITE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST 0
        STB_IMAGE_WRITE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)
    if (STB_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS EQUAL 0 AND
        STB_IMAGE_WRITE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS EQUAL 0)
      check_hash (http://mlpack.org/files/stb/hash.md5 "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}"
          HASH_CHECK_FAIL)
      if (HASH_CHECK_FAIL EQUAL 0)
        set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/")
        message(STATUS
            "Successfully downloaded stb into ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/")
        # Now we have to also ensure these header files get installed.
        install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/stb_image.h" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")
        install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/stb_image_write.h" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")
        add_definitions(-DHAS_STB)
        set(STB_AVAILABLE "1")
      else ()
        message(WARNING
            "stb/stb_image.h is not installed. Image utilities will not be available!")
      endif ()
    else ()
        file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${STB_DIR}/")
        list(GET STB_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST 1 STB_DOWNLOAD_ERROR)
        message(WARNING
            "Could not download stb! Error code ${STB_DOWNLOAD_STATUS}: ${STB_DOWNLOAD_ERROR}!  Error log: ${STB_DOWNLOAD_LOG}")
        message(WARNING
            "stb/stb_image.h is not installed. Image utilities will not be available!")
    endif ()
  else ()
    message(WARNING
        "stb/stb_image.h is not installed. Image utilities will not be available!")
  endif ()
else ()
  # Already has STB installed.
  add_definitions(-DHAS_STB)
  set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${STB_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})
  set(STB_AVAILABLE "1")
endif ()


# Find ensmallen.
# Once ensmallen is readily available in package repos, the automatic downloader
# here can be removed.
find_package(Ensmallen "${ENSMALLEN_VERSION}")
if (NOT ENSMALLEN_FOUND)
  if (DOWNLOAD_ENSMALLEN)
    file(DOWNLOAD http://www.ensmallen.org/files/ensmallen-2.14.2.tar.gz
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/ensmallen-2.14.2.tar.gz"
        STATUS ENS_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST LOG ENS_DOWNLOAD_LOG
        SHOW_PROGRESS)
    list(GET ENS_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST 0 ENS_DOWNLOAD_STATUS)
    if (ENS_DOWNLOAD_STATUS EQUAL 0)
      execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E
          tar xzf "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/ensmallen-2.14.2.tar.gz"
          WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/")

      # Get the name of the directory.
      file (GLOB ENS_DIRECTORIES RELATIVE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/"
          "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/ensmallen-[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*")
      # list(FILTER) is not available on 3.5 or older, but try to keep
      # configuring without filtering the list anyway (it might work if only
      # the file ensmallen-2.14.2.tar.gz is present.
      if (${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "3.6.0")
        list(FILTER ENS_DIRECTORIES EXCLUDE REGEX "ensmallen-.*\.tar\.gz")
      endif ()
      list(LENGTH ENS_DIRECTORIES ENS_DIRECTORIES_LEN)
      if (ENS_DIRECTORIES_LEN EQUAL 1)
        list(GET ENS_DIRECTORIES 0 ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
        set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS}
            "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/include")
        message(STATUS
            "Successfully downloaded ensmallen into ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/")

        # Now we have to also ensure these header files get installed.
        install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/include/ensmallen_bits/" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/ensmallen_bits")
        install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/${ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR}/include/ensmallen.hpp" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")
      else ()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Problem unpacking ensmallen!  Expected only one directory ensmallen-x.y.z/; found ${ENS_DIRECTORIES}. Try removing the directory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps and reconfiguring.")
      endif ()
    else ()
      list(GET ENS_DOWNLOAD_STATUS_LIST 1 ENS_DOWNLOAD_ERROR)
      message(FATAL_ERROR
          "Could not download ensmallen! Error code ${ENS_DOWNLOAD_STATUS}: ${ENS_DOWNLOAD_ERROR}!  Error log: ${ENS_DOWNLOAD_LOG}")
    endif ()
  else ()

    if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mlpack/core/optimizers/ensmallen/ensmallen.hpp")
      set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS}
          "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mlpack/core/optimizers/ensmallen")
    else ()
      message(FATAL_ERROR
          "Cannot find ensmallen headers!  Try setting ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR!")
    endif ()
  endif ()
else ()
  set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS} "${ENSMALLEN_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif ()

set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
  "1.74.0" "1.74"  
  "17.3.0" "17.3"       
  "1.72.0" "1.72"
  "1.71.0" "1.71"
  "1.70.0" "1.70"
  "1.69.0" "1.69"
  "1.68.0" "1.68"
  "1.67.0" "1.67"
  "1.66.0" "1.66"
  "1.65.1" "1.65.0" "1.65"
  "1.64.1" "1.64.0" "1.64"
  "1.63.1" "1.63.0" "1.63"
  "1.62.1" "1.62.0" "1.62"
  "1.61.1" "1.61.0" "1.61"
  "1.60.1" "1.60.0" "1.60"
  "1.59.1" "1.59.0" "1.59"
  "1.58.1" "1.58.0" "1.58")
set(Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE 1)
find_package(Boost "${BOOST_VERSION}"
    COMPONENTS
      unit_test_framework
      serialization
    REQUIRED
)

link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

if (MSVC)
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  set(CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH ${CMAKE_MSVCIDE_RUN_PATH} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
  message("boost lib dirs ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  set(Boost_LIBRARIES "")
endif ()

set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
set(MLPACK_LIBRARY_DIRS ${MLPACK_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)

if (USE_OPENMP)
  find_package(OpenMP)
endif ()

if (OPENMP_FOUND)
  add_definitions(-DHAS_OPENMP)
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
else ()
  # Disable warnings for all the unknown OpenMP pragmas.
  if (NOT MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-unknown-pragmas")
  else ()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /wd4068")
  endif ()
  set(OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS "")
endif ()


include(CMake/TargetDistclean.cmake OPTIONAL)

include_directories(BEFORE ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(BEFORE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/)

# On Windows, things end up under Debug/ or Release/.
if (WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})


  foreach(dir ${DLL_COPY_DIRS})
    file(GLOB dir_dll_list "${dir}/*.dll")
    file(COPY ${dir_dll_list} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release/)
    file(COPY ${dir_dll_list} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/)
  endforeach ()

  foreach(file ${DLL_COPY_LIBS})
    file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release/)
    file(COPY ${file} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/)
  endforeach()
else ()
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/)
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/)
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/)
endif ()

find_package(Git)
set (USING_GIT "NO")
if (GIT_FOUND)

  execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse HEAD
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE MLPACK_TMP_REV_INFO
      ERROR_VARIABLE MLPACK_TMP_REV_INFO_ERROR
      RESULT_VARIABLE MLPACK_TMP_REV_INFO_RESULT
      OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  if (${MLPACK_TMP_REV_INFO_RESULT} EQUAL 0)
    set (USING_GIT "YES")
    add_definitions(-DMLPACK_GIT_VERSION)
    include(CMake/CreateGitVersionHeader.cmake)

    add_custom_target(mlpack_gitversion ALL
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P CMake/CreateGitVersionHeader.cmake
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Updating gitversion.hpp (if necessary)")
  # Add gitversion.hpp to the list of sources.
  set(MLPACK_SRCS ${MLPACK_SRCS}
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mlpack/core/util/gitversion.hpp")
  endif ()
endif ()


include(CMake/CreateArmaConfigInfo.cmake)

add_custom_target(mlpack_arma_config ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -D ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR="${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        -D OPENMP_FOUND="${OPENMP_FOUND}"
        -D CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P="${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}"
        -P CMake/CreateArmaConfigInfo.cmake
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "Updating arma_config.hpp (if necessary)")
set(MLPACK_SRCS ${MLPACK_SRCS}
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mlpack/core/util/arma_config.hpp")


if (BUILD_CLI_EXECUTABLES AND UNIX)
  find_program(TXT2MAN txt2man)

  # It's not a requirement that we make man pages.
  if (NOT TXT2MAN)
    message(WARNING "txt2man not found; man pages will not be generated.")
  else ()
    # We have the tools.  We can make them.
    add_custom_target(man ALL
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/allexec2man.sh
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/exec2man.sh
            ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/share/man
        WORKING_DIRECTORY
          ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
        COMMENT "Generating man pages from built executables."
    )

    # Set the rules to install the documentation.
    install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/share/man/"
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR}")
  endif ()
endif ()

# Recurse into the rest of the project.
add_subdirectory(src/mlpack)


if (USING_GIT STREQUAL "YES")
  add_dependencies(mlpack_headers mlpack_gitversion)
endif ()


add_dependencies(mlpack_headers mlpack_arma_config)


find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  if (MATHJAX)
    find_package(MathJax)
    if (NOT MATHJAX_FOUND)
      message(STATUS "Using MathJax at the MathJax Content Delivery Network. "
          "Be careful, formulas will not be shown without the internet.")
    endif ()
  endif ()
  # Preprocess the Doxyfile.  This is done before 'make doc'.
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile
      PRE_BUILD
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
          -D DESTDIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
          -D MATHJAX="${MATHJAX}"
          -D MATHJAX_FOUND="${MATHJAX_FOUND}"
          -D MATHJAX_PATH="${MATHJAX_PATH}"
          -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/GenerateDoxyfile.cmake"
      WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
      DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile"
      COMMENT "Creating Doxyfile to generate Doxygen documentation"
  )

  # Generate documentation.
  add_custom_target(doc
      COMMAND "${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile"
      DEPENDS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile"
      WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
      COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
  )

  install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/doc/html"
      DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR}"
      COMPONENT doc
      OPTIONAL
  )
endif ()

# Create the pkg-config file, if we have pkg-config.
find_package(PkgConfig)
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)

  list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS)
  foreach (incldir ${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    # Filter out some obviously unnecessary directories.
    if (NOT "${incldir}" STREQUAL "/usr/include")
      set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS_STRING
          "${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS_STRING} -I${incldir}")
    endif ()
  endforeach ()
  # Add the install directory too.
  set(MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS_STRING
      "${MLPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS_STRING} -I${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/")

  # Create the list of link directories.
  set(MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST)
  foreach (linkdir ${MLPACK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    list(APPEND MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST "-L${linkdir}")
  endforeach ()

  foreach(lib ${MLPACK_LIBRARIES})
    string(SUBSTRING "${lib}" 0 1 first)
    if ("${first}" STREQUAL "/")
      # We need to split the directory and the library.
      string(REGEX REPLACE "(.*/)[^/]*$" "\\1" library_dir "${lib}")
      string(REGEX REPLACE ".*/lib([^/]*)[.][a-z]*[.]*$" "\\1" library_name "${lib}")

      list(APPEND MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST "-L${library_dir}")
      list(APPEND MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST "-l${library_name}")
    else ()
      list(APPEND MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST "-l${lib}")
    endif ()
  endforeach ()
  # Don't forget to add mlpack as a dependency too.
  list(APPEND MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST "-L${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/")
  list(APPEND MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST "-lmlpack")

  # Filter duplicate dependencies and directories.
  list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST)

  # Filter out known unnecessary directories.
  list(REMOVE_ITEM MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST
      "-L/usr/lib"
      "-L/usr/lib/"
      "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
      "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
      "-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu"
      "-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/")

  string(REPLACE ";" " " MLPACK_LIBRARIES_STRING "${MLPACK_LIBRARIES_LIST}")

  # Do first stage of configuration.
  set(MLPACK_VERSION_STRING "@MLPACK_VERSION_STRING@")
  configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/mlpack.pc.in
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMake/mlpack.pc.in.partial @ONLY)

  add_custom_target(pkgconfig ALL
      ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
          -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/GeneratePkgConfig.cmake"
      DEPENDS mlpack_headers
      COMMENT "Generating mlpack.pc (pkg-config) file.")

  install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/pkgconfig/mlpack.pc"
      DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/pkgconfig/")

endif ()
```

Tried below command,

`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\msys64\mingw64\include" -DBUILD_BINDINGS=OFF -DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Users\Shoyeb\Downloads\armadillo-11.0.1.tar\armadillo-11.0.1\include" -O3`

Gives error,

`CMake Error: Unknown argument -O3`

Answer (score -1):

You can add it via the cmake run like this:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O3
```

But looks like you really don't need to do provide anything at all as the script you have already adds `-O3` if you don't turn the `DEBUG` option on, which you don't (at least in the post).

Comment: I gave up on windows and installed ubuntu, now I dont have any problem.